# How to iterate over key value once?

Tags: c#, sql

I have following values in the database.

```
Id    key     value
1     btn     one
2     btn     two
3     btn1    three
4     btn1    four
```

I have to display result like:-

```
key    value1     value2
btn     one       two
btn1    three     four
```

I have tried different looping concept but I dont get the final result.

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Also.. you've tagged C# and Java.. pick one.

Comment: in which language do you want?c# or java?

Comment: @javaBeginner: No prob please tell me Java.

Comment: @Vikas as this question is having c# tag so i can not write answer here.Also this question has already got 3 votes to close so it will be closed soon.

Comment: Do you know if each "Key" can have many values? or is it limited to two?

Answer (score 1):

That is tricky if you do not know how many values there will be per "key". One option you can use is GROUP_CONCAT(col)

```
SELECT key, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT value) AS values FROM table GROUP BY key;
```

Your result will only have two columns in it, but the second 'values' column will contain a comma delimited list of all the values. I.e.

```
key      values
-------  -------------
"btn"    "one, two"
"btn1"   "three, four"
```

After that you can process the list in c#, java, or whatever language you are using.